# Toggle Visual Studio setting matching brackets

Tags: visual-studio, formatting

How to turn on the VS setting the shows matching brackets. Looking for the straight line that helps matching items up.

```
    if (true)
    {
    |    foreach (var item in collection)
    |   {
    |<--|----Looking for that     
    |   |<----- looking for that 
    |   |
    |   }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: I think it's ProductivityPowerTools that adds it to Visual Studio. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace That's for 2013, but I saw one for 2015 as well.

Comment: What you are looking for are `Indent Guides`. Try to google "{visual studio version} indent guides".

Comment: Xiaoy312 - thank you. That search took me to https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30 where I was able to download.